# Excel: Solver Add-in: Chaging Constraints issue: Bug, or Misues by me?

Tags: microsoft-excel, solver

I am configuring the solver Add-in for a specific problem i would like to run it on.

I am going to try to explain this on a high level, as, as far as I can tell, this seems to be a high-level issue. If digging into the details is required, i will be glad to provide more detail.

Following:

I have a constraint in the solver Add-in, which you can see in following screenshot, marked in yellow ($B$5 >= $B$3 + 1):

[Original Constraints configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1uUu.png)

I want to change this constraint to

$B$5 >= $B$4 + 1

I try doing this by:

1) Selecting the constraint via mouse-click

2) "Clickling" the "Change"-Button

3) Manually changing the "3" to "4" (see following screenshot)

[Changing Constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggyJi.png)

However, I get following error message:

[Error Message thrown by Solver Add-In](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71Bnn.png)

Not that I think that it should be of any concern to the solver, but both $B$3 and $B$4 are dates, formatted in the exact same way as dates.

Using the unmodified constraint throws no error message from the solver. However changing the constraint from

$B$5 >= $B$3 + 1

to

$B$5 >= $B$4 + 1

throws the error message detailed above in the screenshot.

Have I found some kind of weird bug? Or is there something obvious, that I am missing, in order to get this to work?

THANK YOU!

Comment: That is precisely the error message you will get if `$B$4` contains a text value that can't be converted to a number. (Dates correctly* stored as text *are* converted to numbers.) To test if there's something funky going on with either the workbook or the add-in, enter the formula `=VALUE(B4)` into an unused cell in the worksheet. If you get an error, the workbook is funky. No error means it's the add-in. *The only non-funky cause would be if the date is stored as text in a different format to Excel's default with a day greater than 12 in the default format's month position.

Answer (score 0):

`$B$5 >= $B$3 + 1` is likely evaluating to:

`FALSE +1` (equals 1), or
`TRUE +1` (equals 2).

Solver is expecting the constraints to resolve to either True or False (0 or 1). So the case where the inequality is true and you then add 1, getting a result of 2, is likely messing things up.

Do the plus 1 in the spreadsheet, maybe in the next column over, and change the constraint to reference that new cell.